# Nested Switch Statements: Architectural Design Issue

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project and my task is to add an advanced search and filtering option which allows the users to query desired results from a list of Windows events **by specifying as many conditions** as they want.

The idea is each Windows event log has several properties such as `LogName`, `Source`, `CreatedDate`, `Message`, `Number`, etc. (part of the **FieldItem** enum). In total, there are **four** possbile data types: `String`, `DateTime`, `Integral (Int/Long)`, and `EventEntryType`. Each of these four data types has its own collection of selector operands (part of the **SelectorOperator** enum). Here is a picture to give you a better idea of how the overall structure looks like:

[image]

My initial implementation of this idea is this:

```
 public static class SearchProvider
{
    public static List<EventLogItem> SearchInLogs(List<EventLogItem> currentLogs, SearchQuery query)
    {
        switch (query.JoinType)
        {
            case ConditionJoinType.All:
                return SearchAll(currentLogs, query);
            case ConditionJoinType.Any:
                return SearchAny(currentLogs, query);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private static List<EventLogItem> SearchAll(List<EventLogItem> currentLogs, SearchQuery query)
    {
        foreach (SearchCondition condition in query.Conditions)
        {
            switch (condition.FieldName)
            {
                case FieldItem.Category:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Contains:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Category.ToLower().Contains(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.EndsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Category.ToLower().EndsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.Is:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => string.Equals(item.Category, condition.FieldValue as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.StartsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Category.ToLower().StartsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case FieldItem.InstanceID:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Equals:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.InstanceID == long.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.IsGreaterThan:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.InstanceID > long.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.IsLessThan:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.InstanceID < long.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case FieldItem.LogName:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Contains:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.LogName.ToLower().Contains(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.EndsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.LogName.ToLower().EndsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.Is:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => string.Equals(item.LogName, condition.FieldValue as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.StartsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.LogName.ToLower().StartsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Message:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Contains:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Message.ToLower().Contains(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.EndsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Message.ToLower().EndsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.Is:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => string.Equals(item.Message, condition.FieldValue as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.StartsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Message.ToLower().StartsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Number:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Equals:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Number == int.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.IsGreaterThan:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Number > int.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.IsLessThan:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Number < int.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Source:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Contains:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Source.ToLower().Contains(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.EndsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Source.ToLower().EndsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.Is:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => string.Equals(item.Source, condition.FieldValue as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.StartsWith:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Source.ToLower().StartsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Type:
                    switch (condition.SelectorOperator)
                    {
                        case SelectorOperator.Is:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Type == (EventLogEntryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EventLogEntryType), condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                        case SelectorOperator.IsNot:
                            currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => item.Type != (EventLogEntryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EventLogEntryType), condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return currentLogs;
    }
```

A sample query might look like this:

**Condition Selector:**

```
All of the conditions are met
```

**Conditions**:

```
LogName Is "Application"
Message Contains "error"
Type IsNot "Information"
InstanceID IsLessThan 1934
```

As you can see, the `SearchAll()` method is quite long and not very maintainable due to the nested `switch` statements. The code works, however, I feel like this is not the most elegant way to implement this design. Is there a better way to approach this problem? Maybe by figuring out a way to reduce the complexity of the `switch` hierarchy OR by making the code more generic? Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: IMO, that looks like a candidate for multiple dispatch (visitor pattern). I'll leave the answers for people smarter than me though :)

Comment: What is your data access strategy? If you're using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities this can become really simple (and elegant, too) by using the `IQueryable<T>` interface.

Comment: @Yuck The event logs are returned by `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.GetEventLogs()`, and a list of `EventLogItem` (custom type) is created from those, and eventually are bound to a `ListView` control. `IQueryable` is what I had a hunch about, but wasn't sure how to implement/use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do need two switch statements, but they don't need to be nested. You can separate out the operations to work generically on any kind of object, and then pass in the object you are searching on at runtime.

```
public static class SearchProvider
{
    static Func<object, bool> GetSearchMethod(SelectorOperator selectorOperator, string conditionFieldValue)
    {
        switch (selectorOperator)
        {
            //strings
            case SelectorOperator.Contains:
                return new Func<object, bool>(s => s.ToString().ToLower().Contains(conditionFieldValue));
            case SelectorOperator.StartsWith:
                return new Func<object, bool>(s => s.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(conditionFieldValue));
            case SelectorOperator.EndsWith:
                return new Func<object, bool>(s => s.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(conditionFieldValue));
            case SelectorOperator.Is:
                return new Func<object, bool>(s => string.Equals(s.ToString(), conditionFieldValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            //numbers
            case SelectorOperator.Equals:
                return new Func<object, bool>(n => (long)n == long.Parse(conditionFieldValue));
            case SelectorOperator.IsGreaterThan:
                return new Func<object, bool>(n => (long)n > long.Parse(conditionFieldValue));
            case SelectorOperator.IsLessThan:
                return new Func<object, bool>(n => (long)n < long.Parse(conditionFieldValue));

            //type
            case SelectorOperator.TypeIs:
                return new Func<object, bool>(t => (EventLogEntryType)t == (EventLogEntryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EventLogEntryType), conditionFieldValue));
            case SelectorOperator.TypeIsNot:
                return new Func<object, bool>(t => (EventLogEntryType)t != (EventLogEntryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EventLogEntryType), conditionFieldValue));

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown selector operator");
        }
    }

    private static List<EventLogItem> SearchAll(List<EventLogItem> currentLogs, SearchQuery query)
    {
        foreach (SearchCondition condition in query.Conditions)
        {
            var search = GetSearchMethod(condition.SelectorOperator, condition.FieldValue as string);
            switch (condition.FieldName)
            {
                case FieldItem.Category:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.Category)).ToList();
                    break;
                case FieldItem.InstanceID:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.InstanceID)).ToList();
                    break;
                case FieldItem.LogName:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.LogName)).ToList();
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Message:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.Message)).ToList();
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Number:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.Number)).ToList();
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Source:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.Source)).ToList();
                    break;
                case FieldItem.Type:
                    currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => search(item.Type)).ToList();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return currentLogs;
    }
}
```

*Note I posted this late because the SO server crashed, then I went to bed :(

Hence it's similar to @dasblinkenlight's answer.*

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to handle this kind of task would be to create a custom IQueryable provider and just use LINQ.  Literally, every operation that you are looking for has a standard extensibility mechanism through LINQ expressions.  The basic idea is that you would have `ExpressionVisitor` implementations applying each rewrite rule instead of having a giant switch statement.  Since you can use as many expression visitors as you want, your maintenance and extensibility costs go way down.

I highly recommend looking at [IQToolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/) and Matt Warren's [Building an IQueryable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) blog series if you want to take this approach.

Comment: The tutorial is thorough but is a little bit too complicated for me, do you know if there's any simpler (but practical at the same time) tutorial available somewhere? I couldn't find any on Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid nesting and the associated duplication is to separate the parts of code that extract the value from parts of code that perform operations on it. Here is a small example that should illustrate the technique:

```
Func<EventLogEntry,string> getString = null;
Func<EventLogEntry,int> getInt32 = null;
...
switch (condition.FieldName) {
    case FieldItem.Category: getString = e => e.Category; break;
    case FieldItem.Message:  getString = e => e.Message;  break;
    case FieldItem.Number:   getInt32  = e => e.Number;   break;
    default:                 throw new ApplicationException("Unsupported field");
}
switch (condition.SelectorOperator) {
   case SelectorOperator.Contains:
        currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => getString(item).ToLower().Contains(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
   break;
   case SelectorOperator.EndsWith:
       currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => getString(item).ToLower().EndsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
   break;
   case SelectorOperator.Is:
       currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => string.Equals(getString(item), condition.FieldValue as string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
   break;
   case SelectorOperator.StartsWith:
       currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => getString(item).ToLower().StartsWith(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
   break;
   case SelectorOperator.Equals:
       currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => getInt32(item) == int.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
   break;
   case SelectorOperator.IsGreaterThan:
       currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => getInt32(item) > int.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
   break;
   case SelectorOperator.IsLessThan:
       currentLogs = currentLogs.Where(item => getInt32(item) < int.Parse(condition.FieldValue as string)).ToList();
   break;
}
```

Adding a new source field now entails adding another `case` to the first `switch`; adding a new operation to a type would require only one new `case` in the second `switch`, thus reducing the number of "maintenance points" in your code.

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than my initial implementation and significantly increases the maintainability of the program. However, after seeing others suggest using `IQueryable` and `ExpressionVisitor`, I'm trying to see how I can apply those to my problem. Your answer is definitely a great starting point though. Thanks!

Comment: @programmer93 An approach based on [`IQueryProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryprovider.aspx) would provide a better integration with the .NET environment, but it is significantly more complex (I've implemented a couple of them, and it took a lot of learning - even on top of having working knowledge of LINQ expressions).

Comment: Hmm... Well I wouldn't mind learning it, I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to LINQ, but I feel like they can be extremely useful in writing better programs so I need to learn them at some point. But on the other hand, you're probably right, I don't need to make this any more complicated than what it currently is, considering Windows EventLogs properties won't be changed on a regular basis :) Thanks for your advice, I'll consider it.

Comment: @programmer93 Learning IQueryProvider stuff is a great learning experience, regardless of the approach that you are going to take in the end. It helps you bring your understanding of .NET's LINQ technology stack to a new level. With this new knowledge in hand, you would be able to use other query providers more efficiently. Good luck!

Comment: Keeping it simple is a good idea, the next guy that's going to try and read the code will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why people suggest IQueryable approach. I always thought IQueryable is used to transform C# query into a query in some other technology like SQL (SELECT statement) or XML (XQuery) so it can be executed in the appropriate place without a need to know any specifics of the technology to which the query is transformed to (by you as a developer/programmer nor by your code - no tight coupling to that technology).

Since your query is executing in C#/.NET code, there is no need for IQueryable.

If, for example, you would use native querying capabilities of EventLog service, then it would be great to implement IQueryable to transform C# LINQ to a query string or some other form which EventLog service understands and executes.

For me, this problem looks like a problem of creating composite predicate by chaining predicates, so that composite predicate can be used in LINQ Where statement.

It depends how generic you want your solution to be, but here is one possible implementation which heavily uses type inference and lambda closures to create composite predicates:

```
class Predicate<T>
{
    public static Func<T, bool> Or(params Func<T, bool>[] predicates)
    {
        return item => predicates.Any(p => p(item));
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> And(params Func<T, bool>[] predicates)
    {
        return item => predicates.All(p => p(item));
    }

    #region Generic predicates

    public static Func<T, bool> Is<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string value) where TValue : IEquatable<TValue>
    {
        return item => GetEqualityComparer<TValue>().Equals(selector(item), Parse<TValue>(value));
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> IsNot<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string value) where TValue : IEquatable<TValue>
    {
        return item => !Is(selector, value)(item);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> IsLessThan<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string value) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        return item => GetComparer<TValue>().Compare(selector(item), Parse<TValue>(value)) < 0;
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> IsLessThanOrEqualTo<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string value) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        return item => GetComparer<TValue>().Compare(selector(item), Parse<TValue>(value)) <= 0;
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> IsGreaterThan<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string value) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        return item => !IsLessThanOrEqualTo(selector, value)(item);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string value) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        return item => !IsLessThan(selector, value)(item);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> IsBetween<TValue>(Func<T, TValue> selector, string lower, string higher) where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        return item => IsGreaterThan(selector, lower)(item) && IsLessThan(selector, higher)(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region String specialized predicates

    public static Func<T, bool> Contains(Func<T, string> selector, string value)
    {
        return item => selector(item).IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> StartsWith(Func<T, string> selector, string value)
    {
        return item => selector(item).StartsWith(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static Func<T, bool> EndsWith(Func<T, string> selector, string value)
    {
        return item => selector(item).EndsWith(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    #endregion

    private static IEqualityComparer<TValue> GetEqualityComparer<TValue>()
    {
        // If value type is string, use OrdinalIgnoreCase equality comparer.
        return typeof(TValue) == typeof(string) ? (IEqualityComparer<TValue>)StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase : EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    private static IComparer<TValue> GetComparer<TValue>()
    {
        // If value type is string, use OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer.
        return typeof(TValue) == typeof(string) ? (IComparer<TValue>)StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase : Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    private static TValue Parse<TValue>(string value)
    {
        // We need special handling for Enum type since, unfortunately, System.String doesn't handle conversion to Enum type in its IConvertible.ToType implementation.
        // All other used types (string, DateTime, int, long) are supported by Convert class.
        return (TValue)(typeof(TValue).IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(typeof(TValue), value) : Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TValue), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}

// For easier typing, no need to explicitly specify type.
class EventLogPredicate : Predicate<EventLogItem>
{
}
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
var items = new List<EventLogItem>()
{
    new EventLogItem() { LogName = "First" },
    new EventLogItem() { LogName = "Second bla", Number = 100 },
    new EventLogItem() { LogName = "Third bla", Number = 25 },
    new EventLogItem() { LogName = "Fourth", Number = 25 }
};

var predicate = EventLogPredicate.And(EventLogPredicate.Contains(item => item.LogName, "bla"), EventLogPredicate.IsLessThan(item => item.Number, "50"));

var filteredItems = items.Where(predicate).ToArray();
```

Comment: I like this approach, but the conditions are custom types, and I need to iterate through them, so I'm not sure how to do this with `var predicate = EventLogPredicate.And(EventLogPredicate.Contains(item => item.LogName, "bla"), EventLogPredicate.IsLessThan(item => item.Number, "50"));` since I can't get and determine what the conditions are without iterating through them first.